# How do you use created_at attribute in a promo rule?

Tags: ce-1.9.1.0, indexing, reindex

I would like to use the created_at attribute of products in a promo rule. I need this attribute to appear in the conditions tab, so I can set e.g. if it is younger than 2 months, it shall apply for a discount.

I already set `is_used_for_promo_rules=1` for the correct attribute (there are two, one for customers, one for products) in `catalog_eav_attribute` and reindexed everything. But still, it does not show up. *How can this be solved?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`created_at` is not an attribute, it is a field in the database table `catalog_product_entity`.

I just checked in a magento CE 1.9 vanilla install, and there is no `created_at` attribute (just in case I missed something). I highly suspect you are using a custom `created_at` attribute, one that is not really used. (for example is it attached to the attribute set?) - anyways, that attribute may not reflect the actual created_at date/time of the product.

You will need to add your own custom rule, via an extension, to make this happen. This is really not that difficult to achieve.

I did a good explanation how to do this in another post. You should be able to extrapolate that to your needs.

[Custom Shopping Cart Price Rule - Most Expensive Product](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/42051/custom-shopping-cart-price-rule-most-expensive-product/42060#42060)

UPDATE:
From the comments below, the following additional information:

The attribute in question does exist in the attribute table, but, as mentioned above, created_at is a field in the database, not an attribute.

I am not entirely sure why the attribute entry exists, as that would take time to investigate, of which I have hardly any free. Possible it exists only to allow sorting to be done.

The value/data is held in the field, and I doubt there is a duplicate attribute, that contains the same data. This would make no sense, and it would be duplication of information.

I can point you in some direction to investigate. The attribute limitation for rules are done here: (1.9.1.0, location may differ in other versions)  `Mage_Rule_Model_Condition_Product_Abstract::loadAttributeOptions`

Here you will see:

```
if (!$attribute->isAllowedForRuleCondition()
                || !$attribute->getDataUsingMethod($this->_isUsedForRuleProperty)
            ) {
                continue;
            }
```

which is the code the skips attributes for inclusion.

If you debug from that point, and see what happens for that attribute, or for that matter, if the attribute is even in the list of available attributes found from the code just above that

```
$productAttributes = Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/product')
            ->loadAllAttributes()
            ->getAttributesByCode();
```

you should be able to fgure out why.

Comment: This is what the attribute reads like in `eav_attribute`: `(103, 4, 'created_at', NULL, 'eav/entity_attribute_backend_time_created', 'static', '', '', 'text', 'Created At', '', '', 1, 0, '', 0, '')`. It is not visible in the attribute management, but if not created by an extension (as I did not), it seems to be a standard attribute for me (or a leftover from an upgrade from 1.4.2). There are also fairly many tutorials which use this attribute for sorting in the toolbar, changing its `used_for_sort_by` in `catalog_eav_attribute`.

Comment: Yea, you are correct. Checked vanilla install, and the attributes exist. Never really thought of that. Not sure if they would work 100% like normal attributes.

Comment: Well, the sorting thing works without a hazzle... but the promo rule does not. That's why I am asking :).

Comment: See update in answer

Comment: It isn't the entire answer, but I get your point, will investigate and marked the question as solved. Thanks!